# Retrieve variable within an Array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am trying to create a list of posts from a specific category inside a Wordpress page template by the function `query_posts`.
If I type in the `category_name` value directly in the query_posts' array value (for example `'category_name' => 'france-category'`) it IS working correctly.

But I would like to be able to define the category through a custom field in the page editor.

The `get_field("custom-field")` function retrieves the value I set in my custom field.
So I tried to put the value of my custom field into a variable and then retrieve the variable inside the array' value:

```
<?php
$category = get_field("france-category");

// The Query
query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'echo $category' ) ); 

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    the_title();
endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

But for some reason this isn't working. Is it not possible to use a variable within an array? Or Can anyone tell me whats else I am doing wrong?

Comment: Replace `'echo $category'` with just `$category`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, try replacing `'echo $category'` with just `$category`. Because you don't need to use the `echo`! Since the `$category` field would be having the value that you might have already fetched. So you could just pass that variable.

So, instead of this line:

```
query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'echo $category' ) );
```

try this:

```
query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => $category ) );
```

Comment: Thank you that solved it! :) My bad doing such a simple mistake, i am only starting with php.

Comment: Glad to know that you got it resolved. :) If my answer really helped you, you can mark it as the ACCEPTED ANSWER.